# Can't Check Checkboxes when the Stamper is in append mode

Tags: vb.net, pdf, checkbox, append, itext

I'm using ItextSharp.text.pdf with Visual Basic 2012.  Trying to fill out the f941.pdf from IRS.gov. All was good except it was breaking Usage Rights.  So I researched that and created the stamper in append mode.  This fixed the usage rights but now I cannot set the checkboxes.

```
MyReader = New PdfReader(myFileName)
PdfOutputStream = New FileStream(outFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
Stamper = New PdfStamper(MyReader, PdfOutputStream, Chr(0), True)
FormAcroFields = Stamper.AcroFields
KeysList = FormAcroFields.Fields.Keys.ToList
SetCheck(Index, True)`
```

I'm not sure if the Chr(0) is correct in the stamper definition. I get no errors and the result is KeysList(List of String) is filled with the forms field keys. Calling SetCheck(FieldNumber,True) should set the checkbox.

```
Private Function SetCheck(ByRef Fieldnumber As Integer, Optional State As Boolean = True) As Boolean
    Dim Dstates() As String = FormAcroFields.GetAppearanceStates(KeysList(Fieldnumber))
    If State = True Then
        FormAcroFields.SetField(KeysList(Fieldnumber), Dstates(0))
    Else
        If Dstates.Length > 1 Then
            FormAcroFields.SetField(KeysList(Fieldnumber), Dstates(1))
        Else
            FormAcroFields.SetField(KeysList(Fieldnumber), "")
        End If
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Dstates(0) will hold the value to set the checkbox and if there is a Dstates(1) it would be the off value.  If there is only a Dstates(0) then using "" value seems to turn them off.  This worked great until I used the append mode.

I found some similar posts but the solutions were in JS and I don't know how to translate that to VB.

Comment: As far as using `Char(0)`, just use the constructor overload that takes a `PdfReader ` and a `Stream` and that value will be set for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks Chis, That works if you can accept the usage rights termination in the modified pdf file. But to retain the usage rights you must create the stamper with the append mode = true spec and there is no constructor overload that will allow you to default the Pdf Type parameter and specify the append mode. The example I got this from used '\0' but was in C something,  As far as I can tell this mean a zero byte. I have tried different values here but have seen no difference.  To anyone still following this question my problem is how to check a checkbox while the stamper is in append mode.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I didn't notice your fourth parameter!